# Xcode: use LaunchImagesSource instead of LaunchScreenFile

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, asset-catalog, launch-screen

I was previously using a single Launch Screen File, but I would now like to switch to the Launch Images Source, where I can defined the launch screen files for all devices.

[image]

I have defined the LaunchImage set, and I have left Launch Screen File blank.

However when I run the app on my iPad Mini 3, I still don't get the image I defined for the iPads.

Should I set some other values?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm in your project's `Info.plist` that there isn't an entry for

> **Launch screen interface file base name**
>
> UILaunchStoryboardName

In some cases, changing from a launch screen file to xcassets fails to remove this value.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same values for the `App Icons and Launch Images` section.

Then, the way I have setup the `LaunchImage` on the sidebar has both iPad portrait and landscape selected:

[image: LaunchImage section options]

And have added the 4 necessary files to comply with that configuration:

[image: Launch Image Config]